# Exception caught by widgets library The thrown building MobileScreenLayou[_InheritedProviderScope<UserProvider?>

Tags: flutter

My Debug Console is saying that I and using Null Check Operator on a null value

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter3/resources/auth_methods.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter3/responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter3/responsive/responsive_layour_screen.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter3/responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter3/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter3/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter3/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter3/widgets/text_field_input.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignupScreen> createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bioController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  Uint8List? _image;
  bool _isloading = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _bioController.dispose();
    _usernameController.dispose();
  }

  void navigateToLogin() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void signUpUser() async {
    setState(() {
      _isloading = true;
    });
    String res = await AuthMethods().signupUser(
        email: _emailController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
        username: _usernameController.text,
        bio: _bioController.text,
        file: _image!);
    setState(() {
      _isloading = false;
    });
    if (res != 'success') {
      showSnackBar(res, context);
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const ResponsiveLayout(
            mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),
            webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void seletImage() async {
    Uint8List im = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    //this will return dynamic value
    setState(() {
      _image = im;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(),
            ),
            // svg image
            SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/ic_instagram.svg',
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              color: primaryColor,
              height: 64,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 64,
            ),
            //circular widget to accept and show our selected file
            Stack(
              children: [
                _image != null
                    ? CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 64,
                        backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                      )
                    : const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 64,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            'https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/default-avatar-profile-vector-user-260nw-1705357234.jpg'),
                      ),
```

So this is the part I think they are saying it's null but I think beacuse I put in the picture and It shouldn't have problem? Just in case I'll put my

```
class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<model.User> getUserDetail() async {
    User currentUser = _auth.currentUser!;

    DocumentSnapshot snap =
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();

    return model.User.fromSnap(snap);
  }

  //sign up user
  Future<String> signupUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String username,
    required String bio,
    required Uint8List file,
  }) async {
    //THIS IS MEHTOD BODY
    String res = "Some error occured";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty ||
          password.isNotEmpty ||
          username.isNotEmpty ||
          bio.isNotEmpty ||
          file != null) {
        //register user
        UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);

        //this method runs
        String photoUrl = await StroageMethods()
            .uploadImageToStorage('profilePics', file, false);

        //add user to our database
        model.User user = model.User(
          email: email,
          uid: cred.user!.uid,
          bio: bio,
          username: username,
          photoUrl: photoUrl,
          followers: [],
          following: [],
        );

        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(cred.user!.uid).set(
              user.toJson(),
            );
```

```
class MobileScreenLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const MobileScreenLayout({super.key});

  @override
  State<MobileScreenLayout> createState() => _MobileScreenLayoutState();
}

class _MobileScreenLayoutState extends State<MobileScreenLayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    model.User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser; //?
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(user.username), //!드ㄹ어감
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried to bulid again but I had same result, I try to make the photo instead of Network Photo I tried to make it local/ assets